# Difference between Ember.CollectionView and Ember.ContainerView

Tags: ember.js

I've gone through the source code comments and the [emberjs api](http://emberjs.com/api/) but I don't really feel as though I've gotten a very clear idea at the differences between the two types of Ember.View. If anyone could delineate the situations where one might use Ember.ContainerView as opposed to Ember.CollectionView, and vice versa, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CollectionView = the same child view over and over

This useful when you want to have a view object for every element in an array. For example, if have a list of posts and want to show a PostSummary view for each of them. A typical ember application will get this done by using the handlebars `{{each}}` helper, which has been implemented using CollectionView.

### ContainerView = different child views

Ember.ContainerView when you need to manage an arbitrary list of child views programmatically. CollectionView extends ContainerView. As an alternative you can use handlebars helpers to insert child templates using conditionals around `{{view}}` helpers instead.